# update and save database in a create method using same form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I am trying to use the same form to create a new database entry, display current DB information, and now update the DB information, but am stuck trying to patch in the create method within the controller. I have tried using first_or_initialize and find_or_initialize_by_name, but cant seem to get them to work for this situation. I was thinking of trying a if something.nil? / else type of design. I am new at this and any help is appreciated!

This is my controller (working currently to create new DB):

```
    def create
     params[:student].each do |student_id, attendance_type|
      attendance = Attendance.new
      attendance.attendance_type = attendance_type.to_i
      attendance.student_id = student_id
      attendance.event_id = params[:event_id]
      attendance.save
    end
     redirect_to :back
   end
```

HTML:

```
    <tbody>
     <% @students.each do |student| %>
      <form class="form-group" action="/events/<%= @event.id %>/attendances" method="post">
      <tr>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <td style="white-space:normal;"><%= link_to student.name, student_path(student.id) %></td>

        <% attendance = student.attendances.find_by_event_id(@event.id) %>
        <% if attendance.blank? || attendance.attendance_type == 1 %>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" checked="checked" id="inlineRadio1" value="1"></label></td>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"></label></td>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"></label></td>
        <% elsif attendance.attendance_type == 2 %>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" id="inlineRadio1" value="1"></label></td>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" checked="checked" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"></label></td>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"></label></td>
        <% else attendance.attendance_type == 3 %>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" id="inlineRadio1" value="1"></label></td>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"></label></td>
          <td style="white-space:normal;"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="student[<%= student.id %>]" checked="checked" id="inlineRadio3" value="3"></label></td>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
        <tr><%= button_to 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></tr>

</form>
    </tbody>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am tempted to ask if you have tried to call save on the object after first_or_initialize. It creates a new object if need be, but it doesn't save the new object until save is called on it.

Comment: i have called save on it. I believe I tried calling it correctly as attendance.first_or_initialize?

Comment: You would need to query for the object first. I will answer with an example.

Comment: greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is your missing piece. I do not believe it will help with efficiency. I will explain after.

Using an attribute already existing for your model I would do the following to either find or create an attendance object for student with the id 10.

```
Attendance.where(:student_id => 10).first_or_create do |attendance|
  attendance.event_id = 3 #arbitrary
  attendance.attendance_type = 2 #arbitrary
end
```

OR

```
attendance = Attendance.where(:student_id => 10).first_or_initialize
# a bunch of ways to set attributes
# ... and then
attendance.save
```

Now, why this may be inefficient. If you are going through each student parameter and looping through some attribute you will incur multiple calls. For example, for 100 students you will end up doing 100 separate queries if you loop for a first_or_initialize on every student attribute set. What I suggest is mapping all of the parameters that you require together into one array, doing a where query and then looping through the array. Put them all into one create call as an array, and BAM you cut yourself some serious ActiveRecord overhead.

```
#Just giving some context to the student param keys
student_ids = params[:student].keys 
#Query for all student ids
attendances = Attendance.where(student_id: student_ids) 
#Get a list of ids by filtering out all of the existing ids
new_student_ids = student_ids - attendances.map{|a| a.student_id}
#Create an array to carry your hashes
attendances = Array.new
#Cycle through all of your non-created ids and build you create list
new_student_ids.each do |id|
  attendances << {#assign all values as a hash by grabbing them from params[:student] using the iterating id}
end  
#Create a bunch at once
Attendance.create attendances
```

Comment: That was the missing piece for sure!! thank you so so much!!!!!! Great explanation and examples!!!